# Error resolving version for plugin ':maven-assembly-plugin'

Tags: maven, plugins, tomcat7, pom.xml, cloud-foundry

I'm developing a Spring app, I added EL2.2 to it, which requires tomcat 7. The app is deployed on Cloud Foundry which provides only tomcat 6. Therefore I had to follow this instruction: 
https://github.com/ericbottard/cloudfoundry-tomcat-7/blob/master/README.md

All works fine but I have an error now in my pom.xml saying:

`Error resolving version for plugin 'com.luke.timetable:maven-assembly-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Luke.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository`

I am not sure what modification (if any) I need to perform in the step 4 of the above given instruction, any ideas?

Thanks for help.

**Edit:**
I have changed the like I was advised in the comment below, but now I the problem is that the app does not work on Cloud Foundry. It works when the error is present in the pom.xml, but as soon as I remove it get this error

`java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type avax/el/ExpressionFactory; used in the signature
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.registerELResolverAndListenerWithJsp(ConfigureListener.java:694)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)`

I get the above exception both on local tomcat 6 and cloud foundry, when error is present in pom.xml (the one you gave fix below) the app works on both local tomcat 6 and cloud foundry.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groupId of the maven-assembly-plugin is:

```
org.apache.maven.plugins
```

and NOT

```
com.luke.timetable
```

which means the given information must look like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  ...
</plugin>
```

Comment: Big thanks for your answer! Please see once again my question as I edited it because the error disappear but the app doesn't deploy now to cloud foundry...